# Why is the derivative of the upper limit of the indicial function zero?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have a Indicial function defined as:
$$\Phi(s)= 1-\Psi_1 e^{-\epsilon_1s}-\Psi_2 e^{-\epsilon_2s}$$,
where s is a don-dimensional time scale defined as:
$$s = \frac{2}{c}\int_{t^{'}}^{t}U(\sigma)d\sigma$$.
When I take the derivative of $\Phi$ with respect to $t^{'}$, I get Equation (1):
$$\frac{d\Phi(s)}{dt^{'}} = \frac{d\Phi(s)}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt^{'}}$$

$$\frac{d\Phi(\frac{2}{c}\int_{t^{'}}^{t}U(\sigma)d\sigma)}{dt^{'}} = (\frac{d(1-\Psi_1 e^{-\epsilon_1(\frac{2}{c}\int_{t^{'}}^{t}U(\sigma)d\sigma)}-\Psi_2 e^{-\epsilon_2(\frac{2}{c}\int_{t^{'}}^{t}U(\sigma)d\sigma)})}{d(\frac{2}{c}\int_{t^{'}}^{t}U(\sigma)d\sigma)})(\frac{\frac{2}{c}\int_{t^{'}}^{t}U(\sigma)d\sigma}{dt^{'}})$$

$$\frac{d\Phi(\frac{2}{c}\int_{t^{'}}^{t}U(\sigma)d\sigma)}{dt^{'}} = (-\Psi_1(-\epsilon_1) e^{-\epsilon_1(\frac{2}{c}\int_{t^{'}}^{t}U(\sigma)d\sigma)} - \Psi_2(-\epsilon_2) e^{-\epsilon_2(\frac{2}{c}\int_{t^{'}}^{t}U(\sigma)d\sigma)})(\frac{2}{c}(-U(t^{'}))$$

$$\frac{d\Phi(\frac{2}{c}\int_{t^{'}}^{t}U(\sigma)d\sigma)}{dt^{'}} = -\frac{2U(t^{'})}{c}(\Psi_1\epsilon_1 e^{-\epsilon_1(\frac{2}{c}\int_{t^{'}}^{t}U(\sigma)d\sigma)}+\Psi_2\epsilon_2 e^{-\epsilon_2(\frac{2}{c}\int_{t^{'}}^{t}U(\sigma)d\sigma)})----Equation (1)$$.
Here I used the derivative of the integral function as:
$$\frac{d}{dt^{'}}(\int_{t^{'}}^{t}f(x)dx) = f(t)\frac{dt}{dt^{'}} - f(t^{'})\frac{dt^{'}}{dt^{'}}$$
This yields,
$$\frac{d}{dt^{'}}(\int_{t^{'}}^{t}f(x)dx) = - f(t^{'})\frac{dt^{'}}{dt^{'}}$$
only if the upper limit of the integral, t, is a constant or if t is not a function of $t^{'}$, such that $\frac{dt}{dt^{'}} = 0$. But I'm unsure why the derivative of the upper limit of the indicial function with respect to $t^{'}$ is zero. Can someone explain this or suggest an alternative derivation for Equation 1?

Comment: What do you mean by "the upper limit of the **indicial function**"? Upper limit of the integral is a well-known thing, but "indicial function" is the name you gave to $\Phi$, not the integral, and it is not clear what you mean by its "upper limit".

Comment: As for the upper limit of this integral, $t$, as you already said, its derivative with respect to $t'$ will be $0$ if *and only if* $t$ is constant with respect to $t'$. But you have given no definition to $t$ or $t'$, so we have no way of knowing whether $t$ varies with $t'$ or not. All your calculations you went to great lengths to produce and $\Phi$ itself are entirely irrelevant to that question. The only way to settle it is to know what $t$ and $t'$ are. Also note that $\frac{dt'}{dt'} = 1$ always, so it is curious you felt the need to keep carrying it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair My apologies for saying the upper limit of the indicial function, but it's indeed an upper limit of the integral. This indicial function represents a response measured at fixed time $t$ subsequent to $t^{'}$. The response depends on the elapsed time $t-t^{'}$ rather than on $t$ and $t^{'}$, implying that the differential equation is independent of time. This is the explanation I found in various books to get the final expression of this derivation. You are right, $\frac{dt^{'}}{dt^{'}}$ = 1.

Comment: Do you mean that $t$ is fixed, or that $t - t'$ is fixed?

Comment: Ya, in the context of step response of the indicial function, the assumption is at each step $t$ is a fixed time.

Comment: Then what I said in the previous comment is correct. $\frac{dt}{dt'} = 0$ because $t$ is constant over the range covered by the integral.

Comment: Your clarification on $\frac{dt}{dt^{'}} = 0$ make sense. However, I am puzzled by the book's assumption that "The response depends on the elapsed time $t−t^{′}$ rather than on $t$ and $t^{′}$, implying that the differential equation is independent of time." If the differential equation is solely dependent on elapsed time $(t-t^{'})$, then why only $\frac{dt}{dt^{'}} = 0$ and why $\frac{dt^{'}}{dt^{'}}$ not zero? I fully grasp that the derivative of a constant is zero but struggle with fully understanding the book's assumption.

Comment: What "differential equation" is the book speaking of? You have not given a differential equation here. (A differential equation does not calculate a derivative - it establishes a condition that the derivatives have to meet).

Comment: This equation is just composed of this derivative. But I think I got the point here. Thank you, Paul.